# Trying to change background color of iFrame in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a webpage that uses an iFrame (see http://little-apps.org/lilregcleaner/history.html) and (of course) the iFrame shows up with a white background in IE instead of the blue background in firefox and chrome. I have tried everything to make the background of the iframe blue/transparent include:

- adding the "allowtransparency=true" tag to the iframe
- adding a "background-color: blue" & "background-color: transparent" tag to the inside of the iframe using javascript
- enclosing the iframe in a span tag with "background-color: blue"
- changing the iframe to a div (wouldnt work because I am using AJAX to get the source from a XML file and the XMLHttpRequest object can only be used once)

If anyone knows a solution to my problem then please let me know. I should also note that the only success I had was with style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add the background in the page loaded in the iframe.

Example, modify http:/little-apps.org/lilregcleaner/history/1.xx.html

Comment: Thanks! It looks like thats the only way to do it even though itll take a bit of work.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the IFRAME BODY's `style` attribute to `background-color:blue` works for me in IE8's debugger. (That is, the BODY of the document loaded in the IFRAME.)

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to change the BODY's styles directly:

```
document.getElementById("versionHistory").contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
// get the IFRAME window object, get the BODY tag in that window, set its CSS
```

Comment: Setting the IFRAME BODY's background to `transparent` *could* also work in IE. Haven't tried it.